# How to check if a selected row in a datagridview is empty(has no item) C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

How would i go about checking if a row's cells have data in them, ie not empty/null.

I've been trying the following:

```
        if (dgvClient.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow currentRow = dgvClient.SelectedRows[0];
            if (currentRow.Cells.ToString() != String.Empty)
            {
                //The code that will be here will open a form
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select a non null row");
            }
        }
```

However, it doesn't appear to be working, and I'm out of ideas :/

Thanks for any help, 
Ari

Comment: Why don't you check for individual cells in a loop?

Comment: What kind of empty row? There is a mode which allows you to add rows but this does not mean an empty row!

Comment: may be [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/50e76816-685a-4d61-8c99-31b0aed803fc) helps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.Cells` is a collection of `DataGridViewCell` objects.

You need to iterate through that collection & test each cell to see if it has a value...

```
if (currentRow.Cells.Count > 0) 
{      
   bool rowIsEmpty = true;    

   foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in currentRow.Cells)    
   {
      if(cell.Value != null) 
      { 
          rowIsEmpty = false;
          break;
      }    
   }

   if(rowIsEmpty)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Select a non null row"); 
   }
   else
   {
       //DoStuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another method to check if a new empty row is selected perhaps

```
if(dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index == dataGridView.Rows.Count -1)
{
    //you selected a new row
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
         for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
                    object value = cell.Value;
                    if (value == string.Empty)
                    {
                             //do
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done by handling DataGridView.RowEnter event. RowEnter event occurs when a row receives input focus but before it becomes the current row. For example, move from one cell to another cell in a different row.

Check each cell value:

```
 void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
     dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ReadOnly = checkrow(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
 }

 bool checkrow(DataGridViewRow testrow)
 {
        for (int i = 0; i < testrow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            if (testrow.Cells[i].Value != null)
            {
                // if datagridview is databound, you'd better check whether the cell value is string.Empty
                if (testrow.Cells[i].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
                {
                    // if value of any cell is not null, this row need to be readonly
                    return true;
                }

                // if there is an unbound checkbox column, you may need to check whether the cell value is null or false(uncheck).
            }
        }

        // else false
        return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Surprised no linq answer so here it is:

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
      .Any(x => x.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
      .Any(c => c.Value != null)))
```

DataGrid Rows are of DataCollection type which implements IEnumerable.  You just need to cast the cells and rows.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem to check if the current row is empty in C# windows form, I put the following logic and it works for me, you can also use it if you want to check all the values then place all cells values like 0,1,2,3... or create a dynamic function to check it.

```
 private void dataGridViewProduct_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridViewProduct.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()!= string.Empty)
            { //dowork

}}
```